# How do I change the Default Home Directory of a user? - Xubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, usermode

I am trying to change the default user in ubuntu..

I already create a new home directory

[image]

at the moment, the default user is me, and I'm trying to make `geza` as the new default user.
I already tried doing `usermod -d /home/geza -m geza`, but it keeps showing `usermod: no changes`

[image]

can anyone help me, please?